# What date format is this

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm playing with my android device and I accidently removed my calendar when installing a new rom.

Now, luckally I created a backup using Titanium, and there's a db file in it.
Now, I've opened it with SqlLite and I can see all the events (yeah).

However, the data looks like this:

```
"Kevin <3 De Coninck. Verjaardag"   "851558400000"  "0"          
"FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20361231T000000Z;WKST=SU"
"Babyborrel alex"   "1362852000000" "1362855600000" ""
"Plasma"    "1364234400000" "1364238000000" ""
```

The problem here is with the date fields. There something like: 851558400000

Anyone knows which date format it is, and how I can convert it to a regular date again with sqllite?

Comment: Its most likely milliseconds since epoch-  a Unix timestamp.  Epoch is 12:00am Jan 1 1970 UTC.  Just suck it up into a Date object as an int value and format it as you want.

Comment: dates are usually stored in milliseconds

Comment: Looks like milliseconds since 1970. If that's correct the actual date is 12/26/1996.

Comment: There's a change that anyone knows what's the format for times in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers.

Now that I know that it are milliseconds, I used the function:

```
date(milliscolumn/1000,'unixepoch','localtime')
```